# Table of integers right aligned

Tags: swift

I have a table of numbers that are in an array that have gotten mapped and now I'm trying to present them right aligned for example I have this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
[1,2,44,5,66,77]
```

But want this:

```
1  2   3   4   5   6
1  2  44   5  66  77
```

Not sure if its coming through but I don't want the brackets or quotes if the values were a string BUT I want them right aligned vs left aligned. I figured out left aligned and just trying to see if there is an easy way to do this.

```
var arr= [0,1,2,3]
for i in 0...3 {
    let table = arr.map { $0 * i }
    print (table)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply printing the array and the `description` method of `Array` will show the list of values separated by commas with the brackets.

If you want any other output you need to generate it yourself.

Replace your current `print` with the following:

```
let line = table.map { String(format: "%4d", $0)}.joined()
print(line)
```

This maps the array of `Int` into an array of `String` and then joins those strings into a single string with no separator between them. Each `Int` is formatted into a `String` that will take four spaces and the number will be right-aligned within those four spaces. Adjust as needed.

Comment: Wow, I was so close yet so far..was doing something similar after the fact and can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't forget to indicate that you question has been solved by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Definitely!! Thanks again..and guys on here are hard on a newbie to Stack lol...love it though. ;)